# Как по нажатию на кнопку, выбрать изображение и показать его нужного размера?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel, qpixmap, qfiledialog

В общем, хочу сделать чтобы по нажатии кнопки выходило окно, в котором пользователь указывает где находиться картинка. 
После эта картинка вставляется в `QLablе`.

Есть два вопроса:

- что за команда, которая похожа на `Open` или `Save` в программах;
- как сделать размер картинки, который мне нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Практический все что вас интересует, может выглядеть так:

```
import sys
from os import getcwd

from PyQt5.QtGui     import QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QLabel, QPushButton, QFileDialog

class QLabelClickable(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QLabelClickable, self).__init__(parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class mostrarImagen(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mostrarImagen, self).__init__(parent) 

        self.setWindowTitle("Выбор каотинки")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("logo.png"))
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 400)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.labelImage = QLabelClickable(self)
        self.labelImage.setGeometry(15, 15, 118, 130)
        self.labelImage.setToolTip("Картинка")
        self.labelImage.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)

        self.labelImage.setStyleSheet(
            "QLabel {background-color: write; border: 1px solid "
            "#0DFFD7; border-radius: 5px;}")
        self.labelImage.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # ... по нажатии кнопки выходило окно, в котором пользователь указывает где находиться картинка.
        buttonSelect = QPushButton("Выбрать картинку", self)
        buttonSelect.setToolTip("buttonSelect")
        buttonSelect.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        buttonSelect.setGeometry(143, 15, 120, 25)

        buttonRemove = QPushButton("Удалить картинку", self)
        buttonRemove.setToolTip("buttonRemove")
        buttonRemove.setCursor(Qt.PointingHandCursor)
        buttonRemove.setGeometry(143, 45, 120, 25)        

        self.labelImage.clicked.connect(self.seleccionarImagen)
        buttonSelect.clicked.connect(self.seleccionarImagen)
        buttonRemove.clicked.connect(lambda: self.labelImage.clear())


    def seleccionarImagen(self):
        imagen, extension = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(      # ... похожа на 'Open'
            self, "Выбор каотинки", getcwd(),
            "Image (*.png *.jpg)",
            options=QFileDialog.Options())

        if imagen:
            # Функции QPixmap.scaled() возвращают масштабированные копии pixmap
            pixmapImagen = QPixmap(imagen).scaled(112, 128,
                               Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                               Qt.SmoothTransformation)
            self.labelImage.setPixmap(pixmapImagen)           # После эта картинка вставляется в QLablе.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app  = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = mostrarImagen()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Охренеть, огромное спасибо!!!!! Просто слов нет. Будем разбираться и учиться))